# How to write Snort rules based on MAC address?

Tags: network, snort, mac-address

I would like to create Snort rules based on MAC addresses instead of IP addresses. Most devices on the network are DHCP assigned, and I would like to ignore certain traffic (ex: Dropbox) for some devices without having to use static addresses or DHCP reservations. Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snort works higher up on the stack. The protocols it deals with are TCP, UDP, ICMP, and IP.

Check out the [manual](http://manual.snort.org/node29.html).

Comment: Understood - sorry for the noob question, but I'm just getting my feet wet again with Snort (via Security Onion) and haven't absorbed the whole manual yet :) What is the recommended method of handling this situation? Are DHCP reservations my best bet, or should I look in another direction?

Comment: MAC addresses make sense only on the same broadcast domain. Are you dealing with a small home network with a single router? If not, then DHCP reservations (or ignoring all Dropbox traffic, for example) are the best.